# Hessian Matrix of Matrix Product

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I am not sure how I can compute the Hessian Matrix of a trace of the matrix such as this:

$$ f(w) := \operatorname{tr} \left( B w w^T A \right) $$

where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ square matrices and $w$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector. I guess the trace will cancel out and I know the Hessian Matrix is the second-order gradient of the function in a matrix but I am confused.

I calculated the gradient of this function to be $\nabla f(w) = (AB + A^{T}B^{T})w$ but am not sure how to go on from there.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that your function may be written simply using trace property as
$f(\mathbf{w})
= \operatorname{tr} 
\left( \mathbf{B} \mathbf{w} \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{A} \right)
= \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{AB} \mathbf{w}
$.

Gradient is
$\mathbf{g}
= 2 \mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{AB}) \mathbf{w}
$ where
$\mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{X})
= \frac12 (\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{X}^T)$.

Hessian is straightforward
$\mathbf{H}
= 2 \mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{AB})
$.

Answer (score 0):

Something has gone wrong with your calculation of the gradient.First of all, the gradient is usually defined to be a row vector so we'll assume you meant the gradient to be $w^TC$ or maybe $w^TC^T$ where $C$ is your matrix $AB+A^TB^T$.But if the gradient of is $w^TM$ for some matrix $M$ then the Hessian is $M^T$.But the Hessian must be symmetric so $M^T$ and thus $M$ must be symmetric. There is no reason for your matrix $C$ or $C^T$ to be symmetric.